# mock results of dataframe apply

Tags: python, pandas, unit-testing

I'm trying to mock the results of a function which is called in dataframe.apply(function), see code below:

```
def simple_zero(value):
    a = value
    return a-value

def difficult_zero(value):
    a = np.zeros(value.shape, dtype=int)
    return a

@mock.patch('difficult_zero', side_effect='simple_zero')
def test_mock_df_apply():
    df = pd.DataFrame([[4, 9],] * 3, columns=['A', 'B'])
    df = df.apply(difficult_zero)
    print(df)
    assert 0
```

Running this test results in "TypeError: Need a valid target to patch. You supplied: 'difficult_zero' ". I've tried both patch `side_effect='simple_zero'` and patch `return_value=pd.DataFrame([[0, 0],] * 3, columns=['A', 'B'])`.

Expected output is

```
   A  B  
0  0  0  
1  0  0    
2  0  0
```

How can I mock the results of a dataframe apply?

edit: fixed simple_zero function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct usage of the mock module is as follows:

```
@mock.patch(__name__+'.difficult_zero', new=simple_zero)
```

The target `'__name__+'.difficult_zero'` is a string representing the function definition. As mock doesn't know anything about the current runtime scope, we should pass it along with the function name. In this case this can be `__name__`. The argument to use another function is not `side_effect='function'`, but it is `new=function`. It might have been changed, but i'm not sure!

Hope this helps!